# Manipulating a table and using it as a query on another table

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have two tables that have data in common, but first I need to perform a manipulation on the first table.

The first table:

| level_0 | index | ac | flight_date | Total_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 33 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 87 |
| 1 | 34 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 55 |
| 2 | 35 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 59 |
| 3 | 36 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 71 |
| 4 | 37 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 70 |
| 5 | 38 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 58 |
| 6 | 39 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 45 |
| 7 | 40 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 41 |
| 8 | 41 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 33 |
| 9 | 42 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 42 |
| 10 | 43 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 70 |
| 11 | 44 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 109 |
| 12 | 45 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 100 |
| 13 | 46 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 92 |
| 14 | 47 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 102 |
| 15 | 48 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 71 |
| 16 | 49 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 74 |
| 17 | 50 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 80 |
| 18 | 51 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 64 |
| 19 | 52 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 66 |
| 20 | 53 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 70 |
| 21 | 54 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 31 |
| 22 | 55 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 45 |
| 23 | 56 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 72 |
| 24 | 57 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 70 |
| 25 | 58 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 64 |
| 26 | 59 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 75 |
| 27 | 60 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 52 |
| 28 | 61 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 58 |
| 29 | 62 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 30 | 63 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 47 |
| 31 | 64 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 14 |
| 32 | 65 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 86 |
| 33 | 66 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 82 |
| 34 | 67 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 83 |
| 35 | 68 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 83 |
| 36 | 69 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 37 | 70 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 35 |
| 38 | 71 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 45 |
| 39 | 72 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 42 |
| 40 | 73 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 65 |
| 41 | 74 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 65 |
| 42 | 75 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 66 |
| 43 | 76 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 66 |
| 44 | 77 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 50 |
| 45 | 78 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 44 |
| 46 | 79 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 50 |
| 47 | 80 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 41 |
| 48 | 81 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 66 |
| 49 | 82 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 67 |
| 50 | 83 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 47 |
| 51 | 84 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 42 |
| 52 | 85 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 51 |
| 53 | 86 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 44 |
| 54 | 87 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 55 | 88 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 81 |
| 56 | 89 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 131 |
| 57 | 90 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 37 |
| 58 | 91 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 92 |
| 59 | 92 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 60 | 93 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 61 | 94 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 28 |
| 62 | 95 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 63 | 96 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 19 |
| 64 | 97 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 81 |
| 65 | 98 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 74 |
| 66 | 99 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 26 |
| 67 | 100 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 19 |
| 68 | 101 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 33 |
| 69 | 102 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 70 | 103 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 37 |
| 71 | 104 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 93 |
| 72 | 105 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 88 |
| 73 | 106 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 74 | 107 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 37 |
| 75 | 108 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | 35 |
| 76 | 109 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 77 | 110 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 86 |
| 78 | 111 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 83 |
| 79 | 112 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 80 | 113 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 | 81 |
| 81 | 114 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 82 |
| 82 | 115 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 81 |
| 83 | 116 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 84 | 117 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 39 |
| 85 | 118 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 | 35 |
| 86 | 119 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 87 | 120 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 29 |
| 88 | 121 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 22 |
| 89 | 122 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 90 | 123 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 | 80 |
| 91 | 124 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 36 |
| 92 | 125 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 93 | 126 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 94 | 127 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 95 |
| 95 | 128 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 86 |
| 96 | 129 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 83 |
| 97 | 130 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 33 |
| 98 | 131 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 99 | 132 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 | 35 |
| 100 | 133 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 34 |
| 101 | 134 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 84 |
| 102 | 135 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 82 |
| 103 | 136 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 104 | 137 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 83 |
| 105 | 138 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 29 |
| 106 | 139 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 30 |
| 107 | 140 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 102 |
| 108 | 141 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 40 |
| 109 | 142 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 124 |

I need to calculate the sum of Total_time until it is greater than 2400 by "ac", it does not necessarily have to be equal to 2400, or else, if there is not enough "ac" just do the sum. I need to store each sum and use the flight_date to query the

second table:

| level_0 | index | ac | transaction_date | unit_control1 | unit_control2 | Total_OIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-14 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 10 | PR-AKA | 2023-03-15 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 11 | PR-AKB | 2023-03-15 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 12 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-14 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 13 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-15 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 5 | 14 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-16 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| 6 | 15 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-17 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 |
| 7 | 16 | PR-AKC | 2023-03-19 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| 8 | 17 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-13 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 18 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-14 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 10 | 19 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-17 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 |
| 11 | 20 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 12 | 21 | PR-AKD | 2023-03-18 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |

And using the lowest and highest date of the sum points per ac and consult the second Total_oil table for that period, perform their sum and only then do a division operation between the Total_oil per ac in the period divided by the Total_oil per ac in that same period and store each division of this in a `Dict{ac:each point}`
I'd like to share what I managed to do, but it left fragments of lots and lots of mistakes.

I tried to use `groupby` oy `while`, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: You should give sample data only, not your entire data (first table) here. People wouldn't want to look through hundreds of lines just to understand your data. You need to work out an example that is representative of your data.

Comment: But where & how you are trying is not mentioned + there is no code sample in the question, kindly update the question as what you tried and where you failed so that you can get help on it.

Comment: can you include a sample output and a bit more explanation please? *"do a division operation between the Total_oil per ac in the period divided by the Total_oil per ac in that same period"* is a bit confusing... as for sharing what you *"managed to do, but it left fragments of lots and lots of mistakes"*: please share your code anyway, with any errors it raised and what you didn't like about the output [if there was any]